# Fleissner-Grille / Turning-Grille in Java

Tags: java, cryptography

I've implemented the cryptographic method of the Fleissner-grille aka [Turning-grille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grille_(cryptography)#Turning_grilles) .

Here's the code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class fleissner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter text without spaces:");
        String text = scanner2.nextLine();

        /*In case the text has less than 36 characters, 
        the String gets filled up with "x"*/
        if(text.length()<36) {
            while(text.length()<36) {
                text = text + "x";
            }
        }

        //Case that text is too long
        if(text.length() != 36){
            text = substring(text, 0, 36);
            System.out.println("Text too long. The following part of the text will be encrypted: " + text);
        }

        char[][] out = encrypt(text);
        for (int line = 0; line < out.length; line++) {

            for (int column = 0; column < out[line].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(out[line][column] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }




    }
    //This method rotates the "grille" clockwise 45 degrees
    public static int[][] rotate(int[][] a1) {

        int[][] rotated =
                {{a1[5][0],a1[4][0],a1[3][0],a1[2][0],a1[1][0],a1[0][0]},
                {a1[5][1],a1[4][1],a1[3][1],a1[2][1],a1[1][1],a1[0][1]},
                {a1[5][2],a1[4][2],a1[3][2],a1[2][2],a1[1][2],a1[0][2]},
                {a1[5][3],a1[4][3],a1[3][3],a1[2][3],a1[1][3],a1[0][3]},
                {a1[5][4],a1[4][4],a1[3][4],a1[2][4],a1[1][4],a1[0][4]},
                {a1[5][5],a1[4][5],a1[3][5],a1[2][5],a1[1][5],a1[0][5]}
                };
        return rotated;
    }

    //This method creates a random grille
    public static int[][] creategrille() {

        int[][] a2 = {
            {(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1)},
            {(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1)},
            {(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1)}
        };

        int[][] a3 = {
            {(a2[2][0])%4+1,(a2[1][0])%4+1,(a2[0][0])%4+1},
            {(a2[2][1])%4+1,(a2[1][1])%4+1,(a2[0][1])%4+1},
            {(a2[2][2])%4+1,(a2[1][2])%4+1,(a2[0][2])%4+1}
        };
        int[][] a4 = {
            {(a3[2][0])%4+1,(a3[1][0])%4+1,(a3[0][0])%4+1},
            {(a3[2][1])%4+1,(a3[1][1])%4+1,(a3[0][1])%4+1},
            {(a3[2][2])%4+1,(a3[1][2])%4+1,(a3[0][2])%4+1}
        };
        int[][] a5 = {
            {(a4[2][0])%4+1,(a4[1][0])%4+1,(a4[0][0])%4+1},
            {(a4[2][1])%4+1,(a4[1][1])%4+1,(a4[0][1])%4+1},
            {(a4[2][2])%4+1,(a4[1][2])%4+1,(a4[0][2])%4+1}
        };
        int[][] a1 = {
            {a2[0][0],a2[0][1],a2[0][2],a3[0][0],a3[0][1],a3[0][2]},
            {a2[1][0],a2[1][1],a2[1][2],a3[1][0],a3[1][1],a3[1][2]},
            {a2[2][0],a2[2][1],a2[2][2],a3[2][0],a3[2][1],a3[2][2]},
            {a5[0][0],a5[0][1],a5[0][2],a4[0][0],a4[0][1],a4[0][2]},
            {a5[1][0],a5[1][1],a5[1][2],a4[1][0],a4[1][1],a4[1][2]},
            {a5[2][0],a5[2][1],a5[2][2],a4[2][0],a4[2][1],a4[2][2]}  
        };

        System.out.println("The grille:");

        for (int line = 0; line < a1.length; line++) {

            for (int column = 0; column < a1[line].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(a1[line][column] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Program is using '1' as holes in the grille.");
        System.out.println("");

        return a1;
    }

    public static char[][] encrypt(String text) {
        int[][] a1 = creategrille();
        /*The text now gets split up to substrings with length 9.
        Then the grille gets filled up with the chars.*/


        String text1 = substring(text, 0, 9);

        int[] ar = {0,9,18,27,36};
        char[][] out = new char[6][6];

        int i = 0;
        while(i<4) {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int x = 0;

            while (x < text1.length()) {
                if(a1[a][b]==1){
                    out[a][b] = text1.charAt(x);
                    x=x+1;
                    if (b<5){
                        b=b+1;
                    }
                    else if(a<5){
                        a=a+1;
                        b=0;
                    }
                }
                else if (b<5){
                    b=b+1;
                }
                else if(a<5){
                    a=a+1;
                    b=0;
                }

            }
            i = i+1;
            int m = ar[i];
            int n = m+9;
            text1 = substring(text, m, n);
            a1 = rotate(a1);


        }
        return out;
    }

    //Method to divide String into smaller substrings.

    public static String substring(String str, int start, int end) {

        String out = "";
        if (start > end) {
            return out;
        }
        if (start < 0) {
            start = 0;
        }
        if (end > str.length() - 1) {
            end = str.length();
        }
        while (start < end) {
            out = out + str.charAt(start);
            start = start + 1;

        }
        return out;

    }
}
```

My question now is: How to improve my code? Especially I am interested in improving the `creategrille` method, but I would also appreciate suggestions to other parts of the code.

Comment: This is of course just for practice, but cryptography requires *secure random* numbers, sensibly implemented by the `SecureRandom` class (and underlying implementations) within Java.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint. I didn't knew there's an extra class for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some advice about Java code :

All the Java classes have names beginning with uppercase letter, so instead of  `fleissner` you have to rename your class `Fleissner`.

The `String` java class contains  a method called [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) so you haven't to redefine it.
Your method `creategrille` can be simplified using matrix properties to avoid writing of all elements of matrix, let's start from the begin: you defined the matrix a2 in this way:

> ```
> int[][] a2 = {
>            {(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1)},
>            {(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1)},
>            {(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1),(int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1)}
> };
> ```

This is a matrix that can be rewritten like this:

```
final int n = 3;
int[][] a2 = new int[n][n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        a2[i][j] = (int)((Math.random()) * 4 + 1);
    }
}
```

I defined a final `n` variable containing the number of rows that will not change later in the method. You defined three a3, a4, a5 in the following way:

> ```
> int[][] a3 = {
>            {(a2[2][0])%4+1,(a2[1][0])%4+1,(a2[0][0])%4+1},
>            {(a2[2][1])%4+1,(a2[1][1])%4+1,(a2[0][1])%4+1},
>            {(a2[2][2])%4+1,(a2[1][2])%4+1,(a2[0][2])%4+1}
> };
> int[][] a4 = {
>            {(a3[2][0])%4+1,(a3[1][0])%4+1,(a3[0][0])%4+1},
>            {(a3[2][1])%4+1,(a3[1][1])%4+1,(a3[0][1])%4+1},
>            {(a3[2][2])%4+1,(a3[1][2])%4+1,(a3[0][2])%4+1}
> };
> int[][] a5 = {
>            {(a4[2][0])%4+1,(a4[1][0])%4+1,(a4[0][0])%4+1},
>            {(a4[2][1])%4+1,(a4[1][1])%4+1,(a4[0][1])%4+1},
>            {(a4[2][2])%4+1,(a4[1][2])%4+1,(a4[0][2])%4+1}
> };
> ```

Probably you made a cut and paste to define these matrices: the code can be simplified defining an helper function to create matrix and then call the function like the example code below:

```
private static int[][] getMatrix(int[][] original) {
    final int n = original.length;
    int[][] created = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            created[i][j] = original[n - i - 1][i] % 4 + 1;
        }
    }
    return created;
}
//inside your creategrille method
int[][] a3 = getMatrix(a2);
int[][] a4 = getMatrix(a3);
int[][] a5 = getMatrix(a4);
```

Finally you can create your matrix `a1` composed of the four matrices, your code is the following:

> ```
> int[][] a1 = {
>            {a2[0][0],a2[0][1],a2[0][2],a3[0][0],a3[0][1],a3[0][2]},
>            {a2[1][0],a2[1][1],a2[1][2],a3[1][0],a3[1][1],a3[1][2]},
>            {a2[2][0],a2[2][1],a2[2][2],a3[2][0],a3[2][1],a3[2][2]},
>            {a5[0][0],a5[0][1],a5[0][2],a4[0][0],a4[0][1],a4[0][2]},
>            {a5[1][0],a5[1][1],a5[1][2],a4[1][0],a4[1][1],a4[1][2]},
>            {a5[2][0],a5[2][1],a5[2][2],a4[2][0],a4[2][1],a4[2][2]}  
> };
> ```

Your matrix is composed like this:

```
a2  a3
a5  a4
```

Using an helper function you can generate the four pieces of your matrix and after join them in the final matrix like the code below with an helper function `f`:

```
private static void f(int[][] a1, int[][] piece, int x, int y) {
    final int n = piece.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            a1[x + i][y + j] = piece[i][j];
        }
    }
}

//inside your creategrille method
int[][]a1 = new int[n * 2][n * 2];
f(a1, a2, 0, 0);
f(a1, a3, 0, n);
f(a1, a5, n, 0);
f(a1, a4, n, n);
```

Same approach for `rotate` method, instead of :

> ```
> public static int[][] rotate(int[][] a1) {
>       int[][] rotated =
>               {{a1[5][0],a1[4][0],a1[3][0],a1[2][0],a1[1][0],a1[0][0]},
>               {a1[5][1],a1[4][1],a1[3][1],a1[2][1],a1[1][1],a1[0][1]},
>               {a1[5][2],a1[4][2],a1[3][2],a1[2][2],a1[1][2],a1[0][2]},
>               {a1[5][3],a1[4][3],a1[3][3],a1[2][3],a1[1][3],a1[0][3]},
>               {a1[5][4],a1[4][4],a1[3][4],a1[2][4],a1[1][4],a1[0][4]},
>               {a1[5][5],a1[4][5],a1[3][5],a1[2][5],a1[1][5],a1[0][5]}
>               };
>       return rotated;
> }
> ```

This can be simplified like below:

```
public static int[][] rotate(int[][] a1) {
    final int n = 6;
    int[][] rotated = new int[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            rotated[i][j] = a1[n - j - 1][i];
        }
     }
     return rotated;
}
```

When you write code, try put spaces between operands and operator , this improves readibility of code.

Comment: That really helps me to improve the code, especially the creategrille-method. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

1) The variable "scanner" is not used.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
```

2) Instead of building a string in a loop (padding), I suggest that you use a `java.lang.StringBuilder`

```java
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(scanner2.nextLine());

        /*In case the text has less than 36 characters,
        the String gets filled up with "x"*/
        while (stringBuilder.length() < 36) {
            stringBuilder.append('x');
        }
```

3) Instead of concatening a string in the `java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.String)`, you can use `java.io.PrintStream#printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)` Instead.

```java
        //[...]
        //Case that text is too long
        if (textLength != 36) {
            text = substring(text, 0, 36);
            System.out.printf("Text too long. The following part of the text will be encrypted: %s\n", text);
        }
        //[...]
```

4) In the rotate method, you can directly return the array.

```java
    //This method rotates the "grille" clockwise 45 degrees
    public static int[][] rotate(int[][] a1) {

        return new int[][] {
                { a1[5][0], a1[4][0], a1[3][0], a1[2][0], a1[1][0], a1[0][0] }, { a1[5][1], a1[4][1], a1[3][1], a1[2][1], a1[1][1], a1[0][1] },
                { a1[5][2], a1[4][2], a1[3][2], a1[2][2], a1[1][2], a1[0][2] }, { a1[5][3], a1[4][3], a1[3][3], a1[2][3], a1[1][3], a1[0][3] },
                { a1[5][4], a1[4][4], a1[3][4], a1[2][4], a1[1][4], a1[0][4] }, { a1[5][5], a1[4][5], a1[3][5], a1[2][5], a1[1][5], a1[0][5] } };
    }
```

5) In the `creategrille` method, i suggest that you create a method to generate the expression `(int) ((Math.random()) * 4 + 1)`

```java
    //This method creates a random grille
    public static int[][] creategrille() {
    //[...]
        int[][] a2 = {
                { generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne() },
                { generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne() },
                { generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne() } };

    //[...]
    }

    //[...]
    private static int generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne() {
        return (int) ((Math.random()) * 4 + 1);
    }
    //[...]
```

6) In the `substring` method, the `out` variable is useless, return directly an empty String in the first check and use a `java.lang.StringBuilder` in the loop; to build the result.

```java
    public static String substring(String str, int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) {
            return "";
        }

        if (start < 0) {
            start = 0;
        }

        if (end > str.length() - 1) {
            end = str.length();
        }

        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

        while (start < end) {
            out.append(str.charAt(start));
            start = start + 1;

        }

        return out.toString();
    }
```

7) In my opinion, you should rename the method `substring` to `safeSubstring`.

## Edited code

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter text without spaces:");

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(scanner.nextLine());

            /*In case the text has less than 36 characters,
            the String gets filled up with "x"*/
        while (stringBuilder.length() < 36) {
            stringBuilder.append('x');
        }

        String text = stringBuilder.toString();

        //Case that text is too long
        if (text.length() != 36) {
            text = safeSubstring(text, 0, 36);
            System.out.println("Text too long. The following part of the text will be encrypted: " + text);
        }

        char[][] out = encrypt(text);

        for (int line = 0; line < out.length; line++) {

            for (int column = 0; column < out[line].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(out[line][column] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    //This method rotates the "grille" clockwise 45 degrees
    public static int[][] rotate(int[][] a1) {

        return new int[][] {
                { a1[5][0], a1[4][0], a1[3][0], a1[2][0], a1[1][0], a1[0][0] }, { a1[5][1], a1[4][1], a1[3][1], a1[2][1], a1[1][1], a1[0][1] },
                { a1[5][2], a1[4][2], a1[3][2], a1[2][2], a1[1][2], a1[0][2] }, { a1[5][3], a1[4][3], a1[3][3], a1[2][3], a1[1][3], a1[0][3] },
                { a1[5][4], a1[4][4], a1[3][4], a1[2][4], a1[1][4], a1[0][4] }, { a1[5][5], a1[4][5], a1[3][5], a1[2][5], a1[1][5], a1[0][5] } };
    }

    //This method creates a random grille
    public static int[][] creategrille() {

        int[][] a2 = {
                { generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne() },
                { generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne() },
                { generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne(), generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne() } };

        int[][] a3 = {
                { (a2[2][0]) % 4 + 1, (a2[1][0]) % 4 + 1, (a2[0][0]) % 4 + 1 }, { (a2[2][1]) % 4 + 1, (a2[1][1]) % 4 + 1, (a2[0][1]) % 4 + 1 },
                { (a2[2][2]) % 4 + 1, (a2[1][2]) % 4 + 1, (a2[0][2]) % 4 + 1 } };
        int[][] a4 = {
                { (a3[2][0]) % 4 + 1, (a3[1][0]) % 4 + 1, (a3[0][0]) % 4 + 1 }, { (a3[2][1]) % 4 + 1, (a3[1][1]) % 4 + 1, (a3[0][1]) % 4 + 1 },
                { (a3[2][2]) % 4 + 1, (a3[1][2]) % 4 + 1, (a3[0][2]) % 4 + 1 } };
        int[][] a5 = {
                { (a4[2][0]) % 4 + 1, (a4[1][0]) % 4 + 1, (a4[0][0]) % 4 + 1 }, { (a4[2][1]) % 4 + 1, (a4[1][1]) % 4 + 1, (a4[0][1]) % 4 + 1 },
                { (a4[2][2]) % 4 + 1, (a4[1][2]) % 4 + 1, (a4[0][2]) % 4 + 1 } };
        int[][] a1 = {
                { a2[0][0], a2[0][1], a2[0][2], a3[0][0], a3[0][1], a3[0][2] }, { a2[1][0], a2[1][1], a2[1][2], a3[1][0], a3[1][1], a3[1][2] },
                { a2[2][0], a2[2][1], a2[2][2], a3[2][0], a3[2][1], a3[2][2] }, { a5[0][0], a5[0][1], a5[0][2], a4[0][0], a4[0][1], a4[0][2] },
                { a5[1][0], a5[1][1], a5[1][2], a4[1][0], a4[1][1], a4[1][2] }, { a5[2][0], a5[2][1], a5[2][2], a4[2][0], a4[2][1], a4[2][2] } };

        System.out.println("The grille:");

        for (int line = 0; line < a1.length; line++) {

            for (int column = 0; column < a1[line].length; column++) {
                System.out.print(a1[line][column] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Program is using '1' as holes in the grille.");
        System.out.println("");

        return a1;
    }

    private static int generateRandomTimeFourPlusOne() {
        return (int) ((Math.random()) * 4 + 1);
    }

    public static char[][] encrypt(String text) {
        int[][] a1 = creategrille();
        /*The text now gets split up to substrings with length 9.
        Then the grille gets filled up with the chars.*/

        String text1 = safeSubstring(text, 0, 9);

        int[] ar = { 0, 9, 18, 27, 36 };
        char[][] out = new char[6][6];

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 4) {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int x = 0;

            while (x < text1.length()) {
                if (a1[a][b] == 1) {
                    out[a][b] = text1.charAt(x);
                    x = x + 1;
                    if (b < 5) {
                        b = b + 1;
                    } else if (a < 5) {
                        a = a + 1;
                        b = 0;
                    }
                } else if (b < 5) {
                    b = b + 1;
                } else if (a < 5) {
                    a = a + 1;
                    b = 0;
                }

            }
            i = i + 1;
            int m = ar[i];
            int n = m + 9;
            text1 = safeSubstring(text1, m, n);
            a1 = rotate(a1);

        }

        return out;
    }

    //Method to divide String into smaller substrings.
    public static String safeSubstring(String str, int start, int end) {
        if (start > end) {
            return "";
        }

        if (start < 0) {
            start = 0;
        }

        if (end > str.length() - 1) {
            end = str.length();
        }

        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();

        while (start < end) {
            out.append(str.charAt(start));
            start = start + 1;

        }

        return out.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Why should I name it "safeSubstring"? Is there a way to make the "creategrille"-method shorter?

Comment: In my opinion, `safeSubstring` is a better name; since there's already a substring method `java.lang.String#substring(int)`. Your version adds the overflow checks, so that's why. For your other question, you can extract the arrays into methods. There's probably a way to use a loop, but I didn't have the time to try yet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you have time to try, please let me know your solution!